# Rules between UIP with function extensionality and univalence

Tags: type-theory

I am wondering if there are any interesting rules/judgemental equalities, denoted $A$, which satisfy the following properties:

$iMLTTfe+UA \implies \neg A$

$iMLTTfe+UIP \implies \neg A$, or more specifically Observational type theory.

$iMLTTfe+A$ is consistent and satisfies canonicity.

Where abrrevations mean:
iMLTTfe - intensional Martin-Löf type theory with function extensionality
UA - univalence axiom
UIP - uniqueness of identity proofs

Comment: Not really familiar with this, but is it possible to add an axiom to a theory without canonicity (e.g. $iMLTT+FunExt$) and get something *with* canonicity? That seems weird to me.

Comment: @SCappella from my understanding this is possible, the new axiom could explain the computational content of the stuck terms.

Comment: Ah, so you're including adding judgemental equalities and similar things, not just postulating terms of particular types (like UA, UIP and FunExt do). Ok, sounds good to me.

Comment: Could you please react to @SCappella's last remark. What is the precise status of your $A$? Can it be a judgmental equality? Can I add a new type constructor with suitable equations? Or must $A$ be precisely an axiom, namely an introduction of a single constant $c$ of some type $T$ that is already expressible in the type theory?

Comment: Yes it can add new judgmental equalities.

Comment: So you are not really talking about axioms, but rather new rules. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi, I am not entirely sure how to phrase this correctly, is my last edit appropriate?

Comment: I think it's a lot better.

Comment: A small optimization: since $\mathrm{UA}$ implies $\mathrm{FunExt}$, your base theory could be $\mathrm{iMLTT} + \mathrm{FunExt}$ throughout. Then you're asking for $A$ which is incompatible with univalence *and* with UIP, but it gives you canonicity. Hmm, I can't even think of reasonable $A$'s that are incompatible with both univalence and UIP.

Comment: Can't you just take $A=$"Every type is 2-truncated, but there exists a type that is not 1-truncated"?

Comment: Just kind of squeezing a type between UIP and full Univalence...

Comment: @cody yes, that would fit the bill as long as the resulting type theory is known to be extendible to satisfy canonicity.

Comment: @cody From your comment and googling this would mean Canonicity for 2-Dimensional Type Theory, should fit the bill of what I am looking for.